# Requesting for my class rank information after graduation

Tags: undergraduate

For advance and challenging courses undertaken in one's undergraduate academic career, absolute grades or GPA does not necessarily indicates the abilities of a student. This is especially so where grade inflation is more rampant than before and tougher courses are not weighted.
Class rank might be a more accurate way to signal that student's abilities relative to his/her cohort. In particular, the physics department with which I did my undergraduate do not partake in scaling of grades.

Suppose I would like to obtain my class rank after graduation, what would be the most appropriate channel to do so?

Comment: Do you mean "rank within one course in one semester", or "rank among all of the peers that are graduating with the same degree at the same time"? The former you can ask the professor. The latter I suspect is something that nobody tracks.

Comment: Yes, rank within one course.

Comment: Just ask the professor!